# C function to split complex strings

Tags: c, string, split

Hi Everyone I need to split a string like,

```
["myroot", "prod1" , ["prod2", "a",  "b","c"], "prod3", ["ext", "ali"] ]
```

Output:

```
myroot
prod1
prod2 a b c 
prod3
ext ali
```

I am new in C programming language and I need to figure out this task but. I can not find a good way to do this. Are there any data structures algorithms or ways I can use to do this? Any help would be highly appreciated. I do not expect you to share code, I would appreciate it if you could give me an idea about the c functions and algorithm I can use.

Comment: Have you ever written a tokenizer before? Sounds like today is the day.

Comment: @tadman thanks for advice man but I need to split also the strings inside braces as a whole if a use strtok with ','  I won't actually solve my problem.

Comment: This looks like JSON, use a JSON parsing library.

Comment: Don't use strtok - it doesn't tell you which delimiter it found.  Write your own parser that analyses each character and keeps track of the parse state.  Or just use flex and bison.

Comment: `strtok()` is just a tool. A "tokenizer" can be a lot more sophisticated than that, and will need to be to parse this JSON-like data.

Comment: Do you want to have arbitrary recursion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest parser uses some global state to keep where you are and reads the input char by char and executes an action changing the state on each char. Along:

- Keep state:

  - bool: Are you inside double quotes?
  - bool: Are you inside [ ] block?
  - bool: Are you inside nested [ ] block?
  - an array of strings for output
- Read the string char by char
- `switch` on each char and advance state in each case

  - you read `[`? that means you are inside [ ] block.
  - you read `[` and you already are inside [ ] block? It's a nested [ ] block.
  - you read `]` and you are inside nested [ ] block? No longer you are.
  - you read `"` and you are not inside quotes? You are now.
  - you read `"` and you are inside quotes? Quotation ends.
  - you read `,`? It's a separator. If you are not inside a nested [ ] block, then write output to next array element. When inside a nested [ ] block, then you do not advance the output array element, as shown by your output, but add a space to the current output array element.
  - you read a space? It's a separator - ignore it. Note - don't ignore it inside a quotation.
  - you read anything else? If it's inside a quotation, it goes to the output - the current array element inside the output array, needs to be `realloc`ated and appended.
  - you read anything else and you are not inside quotation? It's an error.
  - etc. handle all the cases and all possible states.

Comment: That's a lot for someone's first state machine, but it's a great inventory of what's required.